# How can I get horizontal scrolling in Jewel List to make it behave as a DataGrid?

Tags: apache-royale

I have jewel list with custom itemRenderer.

My goal is using it as datagrid since datagrid is not available in jewel.

```
<j:Card width="500" id="cardDetail" height="550">
   <j:List id="lsDetail" width="100%" height="420" 
          itemRenderer="detail_itemrenderer">
   </j:List>
</j:Card>
```

and this is the detail_itemrenderer

```
<j:HGroup>
    <j:Label html="{data['field1']}" multiline="true" width="100"/>
    <j:Label html="{data['field2']}" multiline="true" width="300"/>
    <j:Label html="{data['field3']}" multiline="true" width="100"/>
    <j:Label html="{data['field4']}" multiline="true" width="200"/>
</j:HGroup>
```

The total length of label is 800, but the length of list is only 500.
So when i run the code, the field4 label is not showing up.

And the problem is there is no horizontal scrollbar of the list.
Is there some property i miss? and how to set it up ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just use the Jewel `HorizontalListScroll` bead to give the List hosrizontal scroll capability.

Sample code from [TourDeJewel](https://royale.apache.org/tourdejewel) is:

```
<j:List width="450" height="300" className="tableStyle" 
        labelField="label" selectedIndex="1"
        dataProvider="{listModel.iconListData}">
    <j:beads>
        <j:HorizontalListScroll/>
    </j:beads>
</j:List>
```

Comment: This tag could not be resolved to an ActionScript class. It will be ignored, I already download from the last successful artifacts :  http://apacheroyaleci.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/job/royale-asjs/

Answer (score -1):

List itself is Scrollable cause it has bead [ScrollingViewport](https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/blob/d01a9c710341739c9cc21939ba7a1ec9a73e2197/frameworks/projects/Jewel/src/main/resources/defaults.css#L3088). However your internal content is not scrollable cause HGroup default doesn't have scrolls. You need to add bead to make it scrollable:

```
<j:HGroup>
        <j:beads>
            <j:ScrollingViewport />
        </j:beads>
        <j:Label html="{data['field1']}" multiline="true" width="100"/>
        <j:Label html="{data['field2']}" multiline="true" width="300"/>
        <j:Label html="{data['field3']}" multiline="true" width="100"/>
        <j:Label html="{data['field4']}" multiline="true" width="200"/>
</j:HGroup>
```

Comment: This solution will work outside the Jewel List component, to make a HGroup to have scroll itself, but in a List, will make each individual row to get scroll

Comment: Note that - I did provide partial answer to the problem which was simply available at that moment. Build didn't contains your feature yet, although it doesn't resolve above problem, but it does shows some way how containers should be treated if someone would like to have scrollbar.

Comment: Hi Piotr, you're right. I comment that the code exposed is valid itself, but not solve the problem in this concrete case / question. So people coming for this concrete question don't get confusion.